# using multiple conditions inside Aura:If

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, aura

Here I'm trying to check the multiple conditions inside `aura:if`. But this is not working.
Can anyone help me what is the issue?

Here `**DiffValues**` is the attribute of type Integer.
Even I tried with String also, but didn't work.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!and(equals(v.DiffValues,0), lessthanorequal(v.DiffValues,4))}">
                            <div class="slds-grid">
                                <div class="slds-col slds-p-around_medium" style="width: 56%">
                                  <b>  <label for="Charge_Name"> Please select value </label> </b>
                                    <lightning:inputField aura:id="Acc_Name" fieldName="Name" onchange= "{!c.setAccountValue}" variant="label-hidden"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-col slds-p-around_medium">
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </aura:if>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please [edit] the question to explain the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing AND for OR, and also your conditions would need to be inverted. I presume you want a value of 1-4 being valid, anything else not valid. To get there:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!or(lessthanorequal(v.DiffValues,0),greaterthan(v.DiffValues,4))}">
```